# Django get_or_create throwing integrity errors

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer

I'm so confused as to why the `get_or_create()` method should throw error here, I have this in my serializer:

def create(self, validated_data):
    user, _ = User.objects.get_or_create(id=validated_data['message']['from_user']['id'],
                                         defaults=validated_data['message']['from_user'])

```
chat, created = Chat.objects.get_or_create(id=validated_data['message']['chat']['id'],
                                           defaults=validated_data['message']['chat'])

message, _ = Message.objects.get_or_create(message_id=validated_data['message']['message_id'],
                                           defaults={'message_id': validated_data['message']['message_id'],
                                           'from_user': user,
                                           'date': validated_data['message']['date'],
                                           'chat': chat,
                                           'text': validated_data['message']['text']})
update, _ = Update.objects.get_or_create(update_id=validated_data['update_id'],
                                         defaults={'update_id': validated_data['update_id'],
                                         'message': message})

return update
```

It says that: `{u'from': {'id': [u'User with this id already exists.']}, u'chat': {'id': [u'Chat with this id already exists.']}}`

I have checked other threads, but the solution they all gave is what I already have in my code so I'm really confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem was that the serializer could not implicitly convert the id's to ints even though they are specified as ints in the model. So whenever it tried to look for a chat or user with the given id it does not find one(possible uses string id's) but trying to create a new object with the given id will make the db (postgreSQL in this case) throw an integrity error.  Adding  `id = serializers.IntegerField()` solved the problem